# How to properly add files to target rootfs using Yocto?

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to add a single file (index.html file) to my rootfs on target device. To do so, I have created seperate recipe called "webpage". I have another recipe called "apache2" in my recipes-httpd folder. As follows:

```
.
└── recipes-httpd/
    ├── apache2/
    │   ├── apache2_%.bbappend
    │   └── apache2/
    │       └── (some configuration files)
    └── webpage/
        ├── webpage_%.bb
        └── webpage/
            └── index.html
```

The content of *webpage_%.bb* file is:

```
SUMMARY = "Webpage files recipe"
DESCRIPTION = "Recipe to put webpage files into target device rootfs"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://index.html"

do_install() {
 install -d ${D}/usr/share/apache2/default-site/htdocs
 install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/index.html ${D}/usr/share/apache2/default-site/htdocs/index.html
}

FILES:${PN} += "/usr/share/apache2/default-site/htdocs/index.html"
```

But when I run bitbake, I get following error:

```
ERROR: webpage-%-r0 do_package: Fatal errors occurred in subprocesses:
Command '['/home/mateuszm/Projects/yocto/build-mp1/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/webpage/%-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/rpm/rpmdeps', '--alldeps', '--define', '__font_provides %{nil}', '/home/mateuszm/Projects/yocto/build-mp1/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/webpage/%-r0/packages-split/webpage/usr/share/apache2/default-site/htdocs/index.html']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Subprocess output:error: No file attributes configured

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/mateuszm/Projects/yocto/build-mp1/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/webpage/%-r0/temp/log.do_package.25703
ERROR: Task (/home/mateuszm/Projects/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-httpd/webpage/webpage_%.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'
```

Tried lot of things, but still I can't make it work.
I will be grateful for any help

I tried putting the file to directory not related with *apache2*, just to see if that's the problem. But the error was still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `webpage` recipe a version, not `%`.

`%` is used with `bbappend` files to match all versions of the original `bb` file.

Set a correct version, example: `webpage_0.1.bb`.

Comment: It did work! Thanks for the explaination

Comment: Glad to hear that, kindly accept as correct answer.

Comment: Of course, sorry, it is my first question on stackoverflow